# canvas toDataURL from string

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas, base64

I'm new to canvas but have a good working code. The result is to generate a canvas and then convert it to base64.

The problem is that to make it work, I seems to need to have a canvas element in the HTML code and I don't need to show the canvas element on the page.

**JS**

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
...
console.log( canvas.toDataURL() );
```

**HTML**

```
<canvas id="canvas" width=64 height=64></canvas>
```

**Question(s)**

- Can I to toDataUrl without adding a canvas element in the HTML?
- Is my only option to hide it with CSS?

Comment: Have you tried without appending element to document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `document.createElement()`

```js
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = 64;
canvas.height = 64; 
//....
console.log(canvas.toDataURL());
```

Comment: That worked! I also needed to add canvas.width = 64; and canvas.height = 64; to make it work. Maybe you can add that to your answer? Thank you so much!

Comment: If YOU need to specify dimensiobs then siimply add the dimensions to YOUR code. :D

Comment: @BrianPeacock Yes, but my requirement was to have the canvas element created in the javascript, including the width and height in order to make it work as expected. To help others with the same problem I think it's great with a complete solution.